# When to use milliamps or just amps?

Tags: amperage, homework

So I'm doing this assignment that requires me to find missing elements in a power formula (Power = I (Current) * E (Voltage). The formula is easy enough but I'm not sure on the units to use for I.

From what I understand there are 1000mA (also equal to 1 amp) in 1 Watt. So if that is right should I just use amps if over 1 Watt? Or should I just use mA whenever the Watts are in decimal format? I'm really confused by this.

For context [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ziPWvO4GhrxEI9iB3) is the homework. No I'm not looking for homework to be done for me just trying to understand when to use which unit.

Comment: "there are 1000mA [..] in 1 Watt" doesn't make sense.

Comment: When learning, you always want to use full units: Volts, Amps, Ohms, Farads, etc.  If you need 200mA in an equation, use "0.2A".  After you get very comfortable with this, then you might find some shortcuts that break this rule :)

Comment: It is totally irrelevant what you use as long as you are aware that "m" (milli) =\$\frac{1}{1000}\$ and \$1W=1V \times 1A\$.

Comment: If you're always using Watts and Volts, then just use Amps for simplicity. If that yields ridiculously small numbers, you can just convert to mA when you're done.

Comment: Thank you all. I realize that trying to equate mA to Watt is wrong and how to use mA's now.

Comment: Watts = Volts * Amps period. If you use different units you need to adjust the formula accordingly, for example Watts = Volts * milli-Amps / 1000

Comment: Once you get proficient you will realize that Volts * milli-Amps = milli-Watts.. etc.

Comment: See also: [Dimensional Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All equations are written in base units like Watts, Volts and Amps.

So **Watts = Amps * Volts**...

If your quantities are in sub units, like mA you need to adjust the equations appropriately or understand the relationships between sub units.

When starting out, or for clarity, it is normally best to translate everything into the base units first then chose the units of the result as appropriate after to make the answer more clear and concise.

For example:

> 4. P = ? I = 400mA E= 200V

Use \$P = 0.4A * 200V = 80W\$

Or if you like you can do it long hand..

\$P = 400mA/1000 * 200V = 80W\$

Later you can take short cuts when you get a better understanding of how the units affect one another..

like

**milli-AMPS * Volts = milli-Watts**

Example:

> N. P = ? I = 5mA V = 5V

\$P = 5mA * 5V = 25mW\$

Perhaps you can figure out what units power is in when you use

\$mA * mV = ?\$

**Addition:**

Because we routinely use different scales when referring to quantities it is however very important to show the units in your math and results.

In your example image for question 2 you show the answer **.005**. Unfortunately, that answer uses implied units which is a bit if a no-no and will cause someone to ask... ".005 what?"

The correct answer should be **0.005A**, or better, **5mA** which is clearer.